# Azure VMSS derregister with Azure Devops Deploymentgroup as needed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

I have two scenarios where I'd have to deregister the VMs from Deployment Groups:

1) When a new VM is spun up, its added to a temp deployment group, updated with the latest code, then added to the main active DG where builds are released.

2) When Scale Down or instance replacement occurs.

What'd be the way to go on about it, I have a wrapper script in Custom Script Extension that calls another Script in Azure Repos which based on the VMSS registers it in the appropriate group and triggers release pipeline with latest build (Using Arguments). I am currently stuck on how to proceed with next steps mentioned above.

For 1) I used az devops to trigger a pipeline. So is there a way to wait for the pipeline to complete successfully ?

Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand your query, could you provide an example? Do you mean you want to use a script in pipeline to delete a target(VM) in Deployment Group? Is this API helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1?

Comment: Any update to your issue?

Comment: Still not able to figure this out that when VMSS Scales in, the machine which is scaled in-ed goes to offline status in the deployment group. Is there any way to deregister them automatically when scale in happens?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see there is a default way to deregister target (VMs) in Azure Devops Deployment Group. You can list the offline targets and delete the targets you want to remove:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/targets/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Comment: Thanks for this. Is there any way to get offline agents in all the Deployment groups at once?

I've tried $uriRel = "https://dev.azure.com/Org/Proj/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups?\$expand=machines&api-version=5.0-preview.1"
$uriRel = "https://dev.azure.com/Org/Proj/_apis/distributedtask/deploymentgroups?\$expand=all&api-version=5.0-preview.1"

Both doesn't return additional info.

Comment: No, the `machines` expand is Deprecated (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/deploymentgroups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#deploymentgroupexpands). You have you get targets from a particular Deployment group.

Comment: @Anti21 Were you able to get through this?

Comment: Sorry, no. Weren't able to find a solution in scale down case. We just ran a periodic script that cleaned offline agents.